# Play sound in background without obeying iPhone ring / silent switch

Tags: ios, iphone, alarm, iphone-privateapi

My app must be able **to play alarm sound no matter what** upon **receiving push notification**.

Is there a way to configure audio session to play sound:

1. and **NOT obey silent switch** (route may be respected)
2. **upon arrival of push message** (can be silent) and if app is in the background or **even if killed by the iOS** in the meantime ?
3. Sound is played even if user uses any other audio app (unconditional mix).

I do not need to publish this app to AppStore (only for my private usage), so **private API is an option**.

For those who may tempt to propose `UILocalNotification`: those are not suitable in my case since they must obey silent / ring switch.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24750797/3868293

This is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use UILocalNotification, there is the option described here:

http://oleb.net/blog/2014/02/alarm-clock-apps-ios/

In brief, if you opt-*out* of iOS's multi-tasking, and you lock your phone with the app running, you can continue to run custom code:

> If you do not want your app to run in the background at all, you can explicitly opt out of background by adding the UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend key (with the value YES) to your app’s Info.plist file. When an app opts out, it cycles between the not-running, inactive, and active states and never enters the background or suspended states.

However, if that isn't appropriate for your use-case, you might be able to use `UIBackgroundModes` with `remote-notification` to wake up your app when it receives a push notification, but then you'd have to have your own server infrastructure to keep track of your alarms. Even then, I'm not sure if you could start playing a sound while your app is in the background...

Comment: Sorry, but this not answer the question, which core focus was on forcing playing sound withiout abeying ring switch.