# Play audio from app in background like alarm

Tags: ios, iphone, audio, uilocalnotification, alarm

I'm creating an Alarm-like app that needs to play a long audio file (about 15 minutes) when a time comes even if the app is in the background and the phone is locked. As Apple says, local notifications sounds length are limited to 30 seconds.
I have thought about these options:
- Create a new local notification every 30 seconds with a 30-seconds audio each time, and remove the previous notifications. Cons: Will the audio sound in silent-mode? And also showing a notification every 30 seconds could be annoying...
- Create a calendar event and use a EKAlarm (I don't even know if this could do the trick)
- Execute a background silent audio to keep the app awake so I'll be able to play audio whenever I want. Cons: battery drain?

Any other ideas?

Comment: Is there any reason to use such a big file? Does the sound change throughout the 15 minutes you mentioned? If not, you should loop it instead of wasting tons of memory

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOs 8, start playing sound when in the background, alarm clock app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24749150/ios-8-start-playing-sound-when-in-the-background-alarm-clock-app)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32627322/play-alarm-sound-when-app-is-not-running-ios http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11849790/how-to-set-an-alarm-in-ios  Might give you a hint too.

Comment: The reason of using this big file is because the audio is a podcast. I tried UILocalNotifications but it allows only 30 secs long audios so it won't be possible using them. Any ideas?